# RStudio: Matching parens/quotes not inserting space

Tags: r, rstudio

I just recently downloaded RStudio onto a new computer, and ran across a weird issue I didn't have before. I have the "Insert matching parens/quotes" option selected in RStudio Global Options>Code>Editing. When I go to use it something like this happens:

```
print() #matching parens works, but no space
print(df #if I type something it overwrites closing parens b/c there's no space
print("" #same thing here, no space is inserted b/w matched parens or quotes
```

I can't seem to find any option in the Global Options menu to fix this, nor did I find a solution on here. It's quite annoying since it requires me to close functions or strings again since their matched pair is overwritten every time.

Comment: What does your cursor look like? Is it a "|" or an "_"? I think you may have accidently pressed the Insert key.

Comment: It looks like "_" right underneath the second parenthesis

Comment: Press the "Insert" key on your keyboard to return to insert mode. It sounds like you are currently in overtype mode. This really isn't specific to RStudio. This is how most text editing programs work.